# Why is the internet speed on my phone is much faster than my laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

We're staying in a hotel. The internet speed on my google pixel 4a, android 11, is between 90 and 130 Mbps.

On my laptop, it's between 10 and 20. I have an Asus Republic of gamers GL753VD. The latest windows 10 home edition Internet speed is measured on fast.com

Is it because of an old wifi card or are there other factors at play?

Comment: Is the phone on its own cellular network?  Try resetting TCP/IP and DNS on the laptop.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
 and test.  Try updating the driver on the laptop.

Comment: @John no both the phone and the PC are using the wifi. Alright will try that, thank you.

Comment: Run the Ookla Speedtest.net. It seems to give off more of an accurate reading compared to Fast.com